# How to set the "contentType" field in GridFS?

Tags: c++, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm writing a RESTful call to save JPEG files in my MongoDB instance. I would like to set the field `contentType` ([mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/gridfs/#files.contentType)) in the document when I upload to the `fs.files` collection. However I don't see a way to set that field even after checking the [uploader](http://mongocxx.org/api/mongocxx-3.2.0/classmongocxx_1_1gridfs_1_1uploader.html) and [bucket](http://mongocxx.org/api/mongocxx-3.2.0/classmongocxx_1_1gridfs_1_1bucket.html) classes.

How do I set the `contentType` field in the in a document in `fs.files` ?

I am using mongocxx driver 3.2 and C++ 11.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?